# How to make popup window at the bottom of screen in android?

Tags: android, popupwindow

I need popup window to show up at the bottom screen.Anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: Can you please give an image containing your popup?

Answer (score 0):

Use the android snackbar

```
Snackbar snackbar= Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),"POPUP", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a Toast? Then this would help

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```